# launch ie with url from windows lock screen

Tags: c#, windows, lockscreen

I wanted to launch Internet explorer with url from windows lock screen. We have custom url to reset their user credential.

I have installed pGina but dont know how to customize this to call IE. At any point I just want to call internet explorer.

Please help me to get the solution.

---

Comment: Do you *need* it to be IE or would any browser work?

Comment: So you want users to be able to use a browser from the login screen, so they can reset their password?

Comment: @HansKesting most preferably ie but if it is not possible then any other solution is fine.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes thats correct